# How to get precise lengths (e.g., 5 cm) on the screen with tikz, pstricks, evince, and gv?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pstricks, lengths, ghostscript, evince

Let's feed the file `mwe.tex` containing

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{pstricks,tikz}
\begin{document}\noindent
\begin{pspicture}(-1,0)(1,5)
  \psline(0,0)(0,5)
\end{pspicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[-] (0,0) -- (0,5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

to `latex mwe && dvips -o mwe.ps -t a4 mwe.dvi && dvipdf -sPAPERSIZE=a4 -dALLOWPSTRANSPARENCY mwe.dvi`. (On Debian GNU/Linux 11, on which I do this test, `dvips` is part of the package texlive-binaries, and [`dvipdf`](https://fossies.org/linux/misc/ghostscript-10.0.0.tar.xz/ghostscript-10.0.0/lib/dvipdf?m=t) is part of the package `ghostscript`.) As the unit length is 1 cm by default for both `pstricks` and `tikz`, you might think that in the output, we should get two 5 cm long lines.  However, on the screen, I fail to get this length in `evince` and `gv`.  Namely, in the photos below, you see an `evince` window showing `mwe.pdf` (the `evince` scaling is set to `100%`) and a `gv` window showing `mwe.ps` (the `gv` scaling is set to `1.000`).  My screen scaling is set to 100 % by the operating system (Debian 11).  The screen lengths, measured with a traditional wooden ruler, are 8.8 cm on the left and 4.4 cm on the right.

[image: 8.8 cm in evince]  [image: 4.4 cm in gv]

(These lengths don't look exactly this way on the photos due to some distance between the ruler and the screen, but, measured exactly, 8.8 cm ± 1 mm and 4.4 cm ± 1 mm is what you get).

With `evince mwe.ps` (not shown), we also get 8.8 cm, and with `gv mwe.pdf` (not shown), we also get 4.4 cm.

- Why are the lengths so much off in `evince` and `gv`?
- How to get the correct lengths on the screen for `mwe.ps`? (As for `mwe.pdf`, `okular` did the job for me.)

Comment: If you print both documents, you would get a line that is 5cm of length in both cases, I'd assume. And this is the intention actually. Non-px-lengths are virtually never totally exact when measured from your screen.

Comment: Neither TeX nor your other software knows how big your pixels are or how far away they are spaced. The “100%” by the PDF viewer are only a (pointless) approximation. Check the size of the page the same way (or just hold a piece of A4 paper in front of the screen).

Comment: Use a better PDF viewer. Mine (Zathura -- not mine in the sense of "the one I coded") displays the size of an A4 paper with an error <1mm correct. (Still what @Qrrbrbirlbel wrote is correct, that's only an approximation that happens to work out correctly on my setup, no guarantees made)

Comment: You can connect monitors with the same resolution but different screen sizes and have your OS mirror the the content from one to the other. What now?

Comment: i'm surprised you get any output at all from pstricks using dvipdf (actually  have no program of that name in texlive so I can not test. The texlive program is dvipdfmx, but for pstricks you need dvips

Comment: For Evince it is a known issue that the zoom levels don't correspond very well to the actual size when printed, see for example the discussion at https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/evince/-/issues/1335 and links therein (e.g., issue 1803), https://superuser.com/q/1046658, https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=226198.

Comment: @Skillmon Zathura fails to show a Postscript file for me.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel In a proper(TM) world, the OS should know about the scaling of the  connected monitors and interact with the viewers in such a way that 100% actually means 100%.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I've just updated my post. See also https://fossies.org/linux/misc/ghostscript-10.0.0.tar.xz/ghostscript-10.0.0/lib/dvipdf?m=t .

Comment: @AlbertNash you'll need the `ps` plugin (`zathura-ps`) for it to display postscript files.

Comment: @AlbertNash It would be nice, sure. But this doesn't seem to be a TeX problem, least of all a TikZ or PSTricks problem. (Again, measure the page itself!)

Comment: @Skillmon Viewing `mwe.ps` with zathura after installing the plugin `zathura-ps` does the job: starting `zathura` and pressing `z0` gives 5 cm. (However, in case of two screens the length of the bars is different if you move the zathura window from one screen to another one.)

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Why do you think there's no TikZ or PSTricks problem? In addition to the aforementioned evince-issue reports, more problem(s) might lie anywhere between the source file and the screen representation, including LaTeX+TikZ+PSTricks. It might even be the case that these issues interact unintendedly or even cancel themselves out. E.g., over a decade ago orientation and paper-size options set along the source-latex-dvips-gv route interacted in a strange way. You might have called it a bug or an issue, but the result was, erm, surprising. So, I'd not be surprised by anything this time.

Comment: @Skillmon You might consider posting your zathura description as an answer (zathura does the job for me, and it's *you* who should get the credit points).

Comment: If the whole A4 page isn't displayed in the correct size why should a line on that page (which has a length relative to the paper size) be the right length? You could just draw a line with (La)TeX without any extra packages and it would be displayed with the same error. What about letters? These also don't have the right size. However, just because I don't think this is a TeX problem doesn't mean it doesn't deserve an answer. It wouldn't be the first problem that's PDF viewer/renderer or device dependent.

Comment: @AlbertNash well, that's your fault for using two screens with different pixel densities.

Comment: @Skillmon It's not my fault. Legally, these are not even *my* screens. I'm not even sure whether the pixel densities are really different. Anyway, thanks for the posted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me Zathura does a pretty good job of getting the display size and pixel density correct to display a PDF at 100% as roughly the size a physical sheet of paper would have. Using the postscript extension (depending on your distro this might be called `zathura-ps` in your package manager, or anything similar) Zathura can also display PostScript files and does a similarly good job at displaying them correctly at 100% zoom level.

Note that Zathura is pretty minimal and has a keyboard driven user interface, so it might not be everybody's cup of tea.